# Return dynamically created char array from function as parameter

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to return dynamically created char array from function. But returned array doesn't have characters i created in function. I'm using this code.

```
bool test(char** myCharArray)
{
   char *response = malloc(2);
   response[0] = 'A';
   response[1] = 'B';

   *myCharArray = response;
   return true;
}

int main()
{
  char* testArray;

  bool result = test(&testArray);

  char c1 = testArray[0];
  char c2 = testArray[1];

  // c1 is not equal to 'A'
  // c2 is not equal to 'B'

}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `c1 is not equal to 'A'` - how are you checking that? The error is most probably not in the code you showed.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm using MPLAB X compiler.While i'm debugging, when i point mouse on to c1 variable it says "c1 = NULL;0x0"

Comment: *"c1 is not equal...` I beg to differ. [See it live](https://ideone.com/gXOsZn).

Comment: You are probably misinterpreting the data from the debugger. For example, did you actually step pass the `c1 = ..` line when you did the check? Double check with basic `printf`.

Comment: The compiler might have optimized out the assignments to `c1, c2`, since the results are not used in the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig In linker settings 'Heap Size' was 0. So problem is not related to my code. My bad. :(

Comment: @kaylum  In linker settings 'Heap Size' was 0. So problem is not related to my code. My bad. :(

Comment: @NateEldredge  In linker settings 'Heap Size' was 0. So problem is not related to my code. My bad. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not related to my code.

In MPLABX linker configuration 'Heap Size' was 0. When i write necessary value there problem solved.